# Django, query objects BEFORE certain id

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have encountered one interesting problem

Lets say I have objects in my database likt this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Lets consider numbers as ids of these objects

If I want to get two objects after `5`, I need to use this query:

```
MyObject.objects.filter(id__gt=5).order_by("id")[:2]
```

This will return to me this result:

```
[6, 7]
```

Which is right result.

Now I want to get two objects **before object 5**. I do this query:

```
MyObject.objects.filter(id__lt=5).order_by("id")[:2]
```

However, this returns to me this:

```
[1, 2] instead of [3, 4]
```

So I need to query objects starting from object of **id=5**

I know that there is ranged query, but it does not suit when working only with ids.

Is it possible to query objects before certain id starting from this object itself?

**======== UPDATE ========**

There is a catch, sometimes objects are also filtered by another condition and this means that id's are not correlated by their indexes:

```
[34, 45, 46, 66, 100, 105, 211]
```

How it is possible to get two objects, for example, just before `66`?

Comment: Did you use 2 underscores at `id_lt`? Or just 1 as in your example? Because I believe it's `id__lt` as far I've searched.

Comment: @KingReload it should be `id__lt` but still his order is ascending

Comment: @KingReload My bad. Just fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing descending order

```
MyObject.objects.filter(id__lt=5).order_by("-id")[:2]
```

You will get 2 number nearest to 5

---

If you expect never to delete data then you can use [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#range)(between)

```
MyObject.objects.filter(id__range=(4, 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

we can get it by using slicing & descending ordering

```
 obj_id = 5
 MyObject.objects.filter(id__lt=obj_id).order_by("-id")[1:3]
```